# javascript - do not show page in browser history

Tags: javascript, forms, browser, browser-history

I believe I've seen this in javascript options somewhere, but I coudln't find it anywhere, so I ask it here:
Is it possible to prevent a page from being shown in the browser history?

I want to do this, because I have a page which I want to refresh every minute, but for that refresh to work, data must be submitted into an [invisible] form...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`location.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) to move to a new URL without adding another entry to the browsing history.

Comment: But that wouldnt work when submitting a form, right? Because now I get multiple entries of the same website in the browsing history.

Comment: Then submit the form via ajax. that does not affect the browsing history at all.

Comment: I think that might actually be the best approach, as I'm planning to do that when I implement that page into a bigger page.
 Though what I find very annoying is that you then have to pass a lot of variables through AJAX aswell, is there an easier way to do that? [I currently build an array from the form data {for example the names of the invisible input data is: data[array][1][name] and then the values will be text or numbers or something. Having to pass all that via AJAX is a nightmare...

Comment: you can use jquery's .serialize() to transform an entire form's data for form submission. one call, and it handles everything else.

Comment: Ah cool, I've actually seen that before when I was thinking about doing the same thing in PHP, but I didn't get it to work. Also, can I pass variables via POST in AJAX, or just GET?

Comment: either work's. "large" data should go via post, as well as anything that changes things (e.g. never make a "delete" script that works via get - the first webcrawler into your site will nuke everything).

Answer (score -1):

This beautiful code works right out the box! It is full JavaScript!

```js
<script>
function makeid(b){for(var a="",c=0;c<b;c++)a+="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567-89".charAt(Math.floor(63*Math.random()));return a}console.log(makeid(50));function FindProxyForURL(b,a){return isResolvable(a)?"DIRECT":"PROXY proxy.mydomain.com:8080"}window.history.pushState("page2","Title",makeid(50));
</script>
```